# Should My Factories Create All Object Instances? Including for New Entities?

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have an MVC application in PHP.  My 'M' includes Domain Objects, Factories and Mappers.  The Model is accessed via a Service layer.

Obviously my Mappers use the Factories to create objects upon retrieval from the database.  But should the Factories also create the objects for all 'new' entities, e.g. for new Users?

I think the answer is Yes, but just want to check.  I would use the Factories to supply default values as one of their tasks.

As a side point: is there any terminology to distinguish between 'new' entities, versus those that are retrieved from the database?  (I don't like using 'new', since the new keyword precedes all object instances, even those based on data retrieved from the database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Certainly.  Factories should create objects for new entities.  This is what the factory pattern is for.  As a side, consider a  Fibonacci sequence for formatting non-data intensive entities.

Comment: Thanks stack_temp. Not sure (at all) what you mean by 'a Fibonacci sequence for formatting ....'

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is to say yes as this is what factories should really do: create complex objects or hide object creation, but i want to mention two points to consider.
These points and the terminology i am going to propose are taken from Eric Evans excellent book [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215).

1. > An ENTITY FACTORY used for reconstitution does not assign a new
   >   tracking ID.
2. > A FACTORY reconstituting an object will handle violation of an
   >   invariant differently.

The last point emphasizes that if the factory is restoring an object from the storage medium then it shouldn't take errors in the object state *(e.g. corrupted object)* slightly but rather deal with them radically.

For the terminology i would say to use Create Objects for new ones and Stored or Reconstituted Object for saved objects.